# how can I get minimum error probability for this decision problem?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, signal-processing, parameter-estimation

I have the decision problem for 4 hypotheses as follows:
$$H_j: Y_k=N_k-s_{jk},\ k=1,2,\ldots,n;\ j=0,1,2,3.$$
where signals are $s_{jk}=E_0\sin(w_cT(k-1)+(j+\frac{1}{2})\frac{\pi}{2}).$ $$$$
In vector form:
$$\equiv H_{j}: \underline{Y}=\underline{N}+\underline{s}_j;\ j=0,1,2,3.$$
$$$$
How can I find the minimum error probability for equally likely signals in i.i.d. $N(0,\sigma^2)$ noise. (Thess signals are not orthogonal).
how can I cobtain orthonormal signals for solving this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since you are a new user, here are some tips to get you started: Show your basic thoughts on the subject or things you have tried, or parts where you are confused. If an acceptable answer is posted for you, don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the check-mark next to their post so that way credit is properly assigned.

Answer (score 1):

*Conditioned* on the $j$-th signal being transmitted, the *likelihood function*
of the observation $(Y_1, \ldots, Y_n)$ is *proportional* to
$$\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n (s_{kj}-Y_k)^2\right)$$
Since the signals are equally likely to be transmitted, the_ minimum-error-probability
decision rul_e is the same as the *maximum-likelihood decision rule*, viz.

> Choose the hypothesis that has the largest likelihood

which in this instance means deciding that the signal $s_j$ that is
*closest* in Euclidean metric to the observation $Y$ is the one
that is most likely to have been transmitted.
In other words, compute the four sums
$$Z_j = \sum_{k=1}^n (s_{kj}-Y_k)^2, ~~j = 0, 1, 2, 3$$
and decide that signal $s_j$ was transmitted if $Z_j < \min_{i: i\neq j} Z_i$

Comment: @ Dilip Sarwate: Thank you for your answer! However, my main problem is in the calculation minimum error probability($P_e$) where $P_c=1-P_e=P_0(Z_0>Z_1,Z_0>Z_2,Z_0>Z_3)$. Because the signals ($s_j$) are not ortogonal to have independecies between $Z_j$.

Comment: @lewer You need to state very carefully _what_ you mean by minimum error probability. The minimum average error probability? The _conditional_ minimum error probability _given_ hat a specific $s_i$ was transmitted? The smallest probability that a given transmitted $s_i$ was demodulated as specific $s_j$? As a simple answer, read about the _union_ bound or _Bonfderroni inequalities_.

Comment: @lewer See [my lecture notes](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece461/spring98/book1/Signal_Space.pdf) for some ideas on how to approach the problem.

Comment: @ Prof.Sarwate: Thank you for providing me your lecture notes in this field. My goal of minimum error probability is The conditional minimum error probability given that a specific $s_j$ was transmitted(on page.162 of your lecture notes)?